# Xamarin IOS - Tableview not refreshing on PresentViewController when it is a TabViewController

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a TableView that is in a descendent controller of a TabViewController. The TableView has items coming from an API. There is also a create new TableItem form/controller which once it has been submitted I need it to present the ViewController with the table view, with an updated list of items from the API.

```
var storyBoard = this.Storyboard;
var viewController = (TabBarController)storyBoard.InstantiateViewController("TabBarController");

var tabs = viewController.ChildViewControllers;
viewController.SelectedViewController = tabs[1];

PresentViewController(viewController, true, null);
```

This works as expected in terms of presenting the correct view. But until I force a reload like so:

```
async Task RefreshAsync()
{
    if (_useRefreshControl)
        _refreshControl.BeginRefreshing();

    if (_useRefreshControl)
        _refreshControl.EndRefreshing();

    BookingsTableView.ReloadData();
}
```

The view just displays the same items in the TableView when on the load of the page it should be querying the API and loading the list:

```
_bookings = await   _apiService.GetBookingsForCustomer(model.CustomerEmail); 
_dataSource = new BookingTableSource(_bookings, this);

BookingsTableView.Source = _dataSource;
BookingsTableView.ReloadData();
```

Should also note this app is only a simple proof of concept.. But how can I get it to Instantiate my TableViewController whilst still Presenting the TabBarController?

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: if you share your complete sample solution it might be able to understand more of what you are trying to do

Comment: Hey Yuri, thanks for posting. I managed to solve this I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this, just dismissed the ViewController with the booking form and called my refresh method in the ViewDidAppear override in the ViewController with the bookings TableView:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    RefreshData();
}
```